# How to upload an image to server with android studio?

Tags: php, android-studio, server, android-asynctask, upload

I'm trying to upload an image, taken from an image view, in a directory on my altervista server.

I saw a lot of questions like this but they use HttpClient, HttpPost etc. that are now deprecated. I saw a tutorial on Youtube and I adapted it to my app but it's not working. The code uploads the image in the right directory, but if I try to open it on the server, I get a black screen. I downloaded the image on my pc and the result is worse.

[Here what I see when I download the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piOez.png)

[Here the image, that is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB4qt.jpg)

Php code:

```
    <?php
    $image=$_POST['image'];    
    $decodedImage=base64_decode("$image");
    file_put_contents("/membri/motivationalapp/shareImages/" . "prova" . 
    ".jpg", $decodedImage);
    echo "ok";
    ?>
```

The image is taken from an imageView:

```
    imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    screenShot=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

The thread that encodes the image:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        Background background = new Background(MotAct.this);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        public void run() {
    screenShot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
            String encodedImage= Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(),Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.d("debug", encodedImage);
            background.uploadShareImage(encodedImage); //call to AsyncTask
        }
    }).start();
```

The upload of the image in the Asynctask class:
doInBackground Method:

```
    final String urlServer = "http://aaa.altervista.org/fileUp/shareImage.php";

                encodedImage=strings[1];
                try {
                    //connecting to server
                    url = new URL(urlServer);
                    httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
                    //encode data for post method
                    String dati = URLEncoder.encode("image", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(encodedImage, "UTF-8");
                    bufferedWriter.write(dati);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    OS.close();

                    //read server answer
                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((inputStream)));
                    stringBuilder= new StringBuilder();

                    while((risposta=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                        stringBuilder.append(risposta+"\n");
                    }

                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                    risposta=stringBuilder.toString().trim();
                    if(risposta.equals("ok")) 
                        return 1;
                    else
                        return 100;

                }catch (MalformedURLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Hope you guys can help me.
Thanks

Comment: Could you please upload the image so I can see what is wrong with it?

Comment: @ somega Of course! I added links to the image

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the php file:

```
    <?php
        $image=$_POST['image'];    
        $decodedImage=base64_decode($image); //no double quotes
        file_put_contents("/membri/motivationalapp/shareImages/" . "prova" . ".JPEG", $decodedImage); //JPEG instead of jpg
        echo "ok";
    ?>
```

Comment: Both should not be a problem.

Comment: @somega you're right...so I'm really confused. Before those modification it didn't work.

Comment: I tried this: I copied the code above in a file on the server and it didn't work, I made the modifications of this answer and it started to work...